# How to associate labels with radio buttons

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC, and I've got a simple radio button setup:

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("my_flag", True)%><label>Yes</label>
<%=Html.RadioButton("my_flag", False)%><label>No</label>
```

The only thing I'm missing is that you can't click the label to select the radio button. Normally you'd use:

```
<label for="my_flag">
```

but that associates both labels with the last radio button. Is there any way to associate the labels with the correct radio button?

Note: This is mimicking a paper form, so switching to a checkbox is not an option.

Comment: Even with the accepted answer you need to override the ID as given example of in my answer. If you don't do this, your HTML will fail validation as two elements with the same ID is present.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320172/use-html-radiobuttonfor-and-html-labelfor-for-the-same-model-but-different-value

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to give the two radio buttons the same **name** (so that they're in the same group), but different **ids** (so that you can associate the label with each one individually). I'm not familiar with ASP.NET MVC, so I don't know how to actually accomplish this, but that's the solution.

Edit: a second possibility is to wrap the radio buttons inside the label tag, like so:

```
<label><%=Html.RadioButton("my_flag", True)%>Yes</label>
<label><%=Html.RadioButton("my_flag", False)%>No</label>
```

** Note that this way may actually have better browser compatibility, I know some browsers are still iffy about the name/id distinction*

Comment: Im afraid this solution produces invalid html where id is dublicated

Comment: It very well may. As I said, I don't know anything about ASP.NET MVC, I have no idea whether that first argument defines the id or the name attribute.

Comment: Defines both the id and the name.

Comment: This is not 508 compliant.  the label button must use a for="idOfElement" to pass html5 validation and US Government 508 compliance. See solution below from Troels

<label for="option_yes">Yes:</label>
 <%=Html.RadioButton("option", "yes", new { id = "option_yes" }) %>

Answer (score 42):

You have two different ways to implement this.

The first one is the simple solution is to embed the radio button inside a `<label/>` tag.

```
<p>
    <label><%=Html.RadioButton("option", "yes") %> Yes</label>
</p>

<p>
    <label><%=Html.RadioButton("option", "no") %> No</label>
</p>
```

The second path is to associate each radio button with an ID. This is also quite simple with the `htmlAttributes` argument and it allows for more flexibility in regard to the form layout:

```
<p>
    <label for="option_yes">Yes:</label>
    <%=Html.RadioButton("option", "yes", new { id = "option_yes" }) %>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="option_no">Np:</label>
    <%=Html.RadioButton("option", "no", new { id = "option_no" }) %>
</p>
```

I would recommend the latter, and it seems to be the one you are asking for too.

**EDIT**

In fact you should give the argument with the ID attribute no matter what. If you don't do this, your site will have multiple elements with the same ID, and this fails HTML validation.

Comment: +1 I liked the first way. Here is no need to give the each radio button an ID. But is this cross browser compatible..??

Answer (score 15):

I'm not an asp programmer, so sorry if i'll tell something off :P

Label's attribute for is referenced to input's id. So you will have to do something like

```
<input type="radio" name="rad1" id="rad1_1"><label for="rad1_1">Rad1</label>
<input type="radio" name="rad1" id="rad1_2"><label for="rad1_2">Rad2</label>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this: (This is using Razor, but it's easy to translate.)

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyValue, true, new { id = "MyValue_True" })
<label for="MyValue_True">Yes, this is true</label>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyValue, false, new { id = "MyValue_False" })
<label for="MyValue_False">No, this is false</label>
```

Basically you manually specify the `id` attribute for the radio buttons.