# Rails - How to make a conditional Radio Button checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a radio button like so:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'permission[role_id]', '2' %>
```

How can I make the radio buttons checked status condition. To only be checked if @permission.role_id.nil? or if @permission.role_id == 2?

I tried:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'permission[role_id]', '2', @permission.role_id.nil? ? {:checked => true} : {:checked => false} %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[The documentation for `radio_button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag) says that `checked` isn't an options hash parameter, it's just a normal one:

```
radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})
```

So, you need to do this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'permission[role_id]', '2', !!(@permission.role_id.nil? || @permission.role_id == 2) %>
```

Comment: Neglects to account for the case of `@permission.role_id == 2` as requested in the original question. Also, why not just use `:checked => !!@permission.role_id.nil?` sans ternary? Much more Ruby-esque.

Comment: Just tried it but no luck. Also had to update it to solve for the two use cases above... Ideas?         <%= radio_button_tag 'permission[role_id]', '2', { :checked => ( (@permission.role_id.nil? || (@permission.role_id == 2)  ? true : false) } %>

Comment: Strange, even doing { :checked => ( @permission.role_id == 2 ? false : false ) } is always checked true

Comment: @coreyward Thanks for the feedback - I'm using the double-bang now.

Comment: @AnApprentice - I've edited the answer - the problem was that `checked` isn't passed in the options hash, it's just a standard parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 7, the answer given by @skilldrick doesn't work. You have to use a hash instead of a just parameter.

```
...
form.radio_button :example_field, :example_value, checked:(example_value == "Example Value")
```