# How to alter the view based on which radio button is selected (without javascript) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

I have a form with radio buttons on a page. 
I also have a helper method called vanish that adds
`raw' style="display: none;" '`.

In my view I would like to be able to call a boolean value based on which radio button is selected to activate/deactivate the helper method. The goal would look something like this

```
<p <%= vanish unless x %> > Stuff that only shows when a certain radio button is selected </p>
```

I am trying to do this without JavaScript. I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13

If you need anything else let me know.

Edit. I have seen this done in rails 2.3 where x would be `params[:name] != 'value`. This however does not dynamically change the page in rails 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this stuff to change after the page loads, you *must* use JavaScript. All your Ruby code is going to be executed before the user sees the page.

If this only has to do with the *initial* view of the page, then you're fine - all you need to do is have a variable that determines which button starts out selected, and use it for both the conditional (`x`, in your code), and elsewhere in the view where you display the radio buttons - see [Rails - How to make a conditional Radio Button checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708910/rails-how-to-make-a-conditional-radio-button-checked) for details on setting a default selected radio button like this.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea if it was different in an earlier version of rails. In 2.3 that boolean would be a `params[:*] == 'name'`, but that does not work in 3.2.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that usage, but JS has always been required to make pages respond when the user interacts with form elements. Older version of Rails sometimes tried to write JS for you, which may have been what you describe. They've moved away from that in the last several versions.

Comment: I will double check, when I looked at the older example I did not see any traces of JavaScript