# How to make radio button checked by default based on different user role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

```
<% if role.name == "Administrator" %>
     <%= f.radio_button:status,'available', :checked => (params[:status] == nil ? true : params[:status]) %><label>Available</label>
     <%= f.radio_button:_status,'not available' %><label>Not Available</label>
<% else %>
     <%= f.radio_button:_status,'available' %><label>Available</label>
     <%= f.radio_button:_status,'not available' %><label>Not Available</label>
<% end %>
```

By default i want the `available` radio button to be checked in case of administrator and `not available` radio button for rest of user. But he can change it and when viewing for editing it should show the one he/she has selected and not the default one.

How can i do this? please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708910/rails-how-to-make-a-conditional-radio-button-checked

Comment: @KeesSonnema: I dont think there is any thing that is similar to what they have asked for. Please read my question again and check for difference.

Answer (score 38):

Try the following code.

```
<%= f.radio_button:_status,'available', :checked => (role.name == "Administrator") %><label>Available</label>
<%= f.radio_button:_status,'not available', :checked => (role.name != "Administrator") %><label>Not Available</label>
```

Comment: This will not work, because `checked` will always be `true` if it is inserted in an HTML element, no matter what it is set as. You can [read more on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228658/what-values-for-checked-and-selected-are-false)

Comment: Actually, this will work, at least in Rails 5 it does.

Comment: It works because if checked is false, Rails does not include the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the documentation for rails [radio_button_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag) you would see it accepts the following params:

```
radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})
```

So it would be enough the following code

```
<%= f.radio_button:_status,'available', role.name == "Administrator" %><label>Available</label>
<%= f.radio_button:_status,'not available', role.name != "Administrator" %><label>Not Available</label>
```

Without the need of adding a "checked" property that might result in an unwanted behaviour