# Ruby view unable to map values to boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I want a radio button with 2 value. It's default value is set as false. Currently, the data is not saved into the database. I have scoured SO and look at [ruby's form_helper docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and still can't seem to find out what's wrong with my code.

This code is supposed to be in index.html.erb

```
  <div>
    <%= form.label :is_done, "Done", :value => true %>
    <%= form.radio_button :is_done, true %>
  </div>
  <br>
```

I have also tried this method

```
  <div>
    <%= form.radio_button :is_done, true %>
    <%= form.label :is_done, "True", :value => true %>
    <%= form.radio_button :is_done, false %>
    <%= form.label :is_done, "False", :value => false %>
  </div>
```

Edit: both versions are working perfectly, some random undo and redo fixed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746387/labels-for-radio-buttons-in-rails-form) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060268/how-to-use-radio-button-correctly-in-rails) questions, it should be like this:

```
  <div>
    <%= form.label :is_done, "Done", :value => "true" %>
    <%= form.radio_button :is_done, true, checked: "true" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: hope you have permitted it into the params

Comment: can you show us the code for creating tasks in the controller?

Comment: you have to permit parameters like params.require(:task).permit(:name,  :is_done )

Comment: before you save the task can you show us whats inside params?

Comment: After some random undo and redo, it magically worked for some reason. I can't find out what have I done which caused it to work. Thanks for your help anyw