# more radio buttons in simple form are being generated than should be

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, simple-form

I am trying to make radio buttons with simple form.  I have the following code:

```
<%= f.input :payment_method, as: :radio_buttons, input_html:{value: 'venmo', id: 'venmo', style: 'float: left;'}%> 
<%= f.input :payment_method, as: :radio_buttons, input_html: {value: 'checking_account', id: 'checking_account', style: 'float: left'}, required: true  %>
```

For some reason, this is creating 4 radio buttons instead of 2 with labels "yes" and "no" that i don't want.  Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is the html that is generated:

```
<div class="input radio_buttons required freelancer_account_mimic_payment_method">
    <label class="radio_buttons required" for="checking_account">
        <abbr title="required"></abbr>
         Payment method
    </label>
    <span class="radio radio">
        <input id="checking_account" class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="true" style="float: left" required="required" name="freelancer_account_mimic[payment_method]" aria-required="true"></input>
        <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="freelancer_account_mimic_payment_method_true">
            Yes
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="radio radio">
        <input id="checking_account" class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="false" style="float: left" required="required" name="freelancer_account_mimic[payment_method]" aria-required="true"></input>
        <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="freelancer_account_mimic_payment_method_false">
            No
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

How do I fix this so only two radio buttons appear with labels that I choose?

Comment: Possibly the same as  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746387/labels-for-radio-buttons-in-rails-form ?

Comment: Thanks, but not a duplicate.  My question is for simple form - not the regular  rails form helpers.  Also, that question does not explain the extra radio buttons popping up.

Comment: You seem to be using radiobuttons (plural), they're using radiobutton (singular). I think the plural version create a Yes/No buttons

Comment: Removing the `float: left` would let you see whats happening better. I tend to avoid floats and use `display: inline` or `inline-block` since floats mess with layout in annoying ways.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.  I changed it to singular and the server logs say "ActionView::Template::Error (No input found for radio_button):"

Comment: there is no such thing with simple form, only f.input

Comment: Looking at the Collection section of the documentation, would `f.input :payment_method, collection: ['Checking Account', 'Venmo']` work