# Missing template in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application, I want to get controls value into controllers page:

```
    below is view page:
<%= form_for :managerviewresume, :url => { :method => :post, :action => :managerviewresume }) do |f| %>
        <table class="table" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><%= @selection %></td> //Here I am checking radio button value
                <td>
                    <label style="font-size:small;">Selected?</label>
                    <label class="radio inline" style="font-size: small">
                    </br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <%= f.radio_button :select, "Yes", :id => "rb_select1" %>
                    Yes
                    </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label class="radio inline" style="font-size: small">
                    <%= f.radio_button :select, "No", :id => "rb_select2" %>
                    No
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= f.submit "Save", { :class => "stylbutton" } %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    <% end %>
```

below is controllers page:

```
class ManagersController < ApplicationController
  def managerviewresume
    @selection = params[:select]
    render "managerviewresumes"
  end
end
```

In the controller's page I am getting below error at this line `render 'managerviewresumes'` :

```
Missing template managers/managerviewresumes, application/managerviewresumes with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/VideoResume/app/views"
```

below is the route:

```
  match '/managerviewresumes',  to: 'managers#managerviewresume', via: 'get'
```

Kindly suggest what should I do get `radio button` value from `view` page into `controller` page.
waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. inspect the params 2. error is clear `Missing template ...`

Comment: First I want to check params get value correctly  from view page into this variable `@selection` that's why I am doing this `<td><%= @selection %></td>` into the view page

Comment: use `puts params.inspect` in your `action` and check the `log`

Comment: can you specify the action and method thier? I think it will resolve your problem actually its not geeting what type of request is .e.post or get

Comment: my post is working fine when I remove this `render "managerviewresumes"` from controller page, but I want that whan i click on radio button, the radio button value show into the `managerviewresumes` page at this line `<%= @selection %>`

Answer (score 1):

**Render**

Firstly, you don't need to use `render` to render the same view as your `action` name

When using a Rails controller, you can call this without issue:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def your_action
       #-> will automatically render the "your_action" view
   end
end
```

So I would remove your reference to the `render` action (as it is an unnecessary step). This will not resolve the issue directly, but should ensure your application is more [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)

--

**Routes**

Secondly, you *may* need to look at [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

In Rails' routing structure, you are able to call `resources :controller` to generate a series of `RESTful` routes:

[image]

I understand you likely want to keep using your action, but for the sake of correctness, can I recommend you look into your `config/routes.rb` file & ensure you're using as many resource-based routes as possible:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :managers do
   collection do
       post :managerviewresume
   end 
end
```

--

**Form**

Finally, I think your form needs to be improved

You're using [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), which is mainly for ActiveRecord objects (if you want to create new record etc. It seems you'll be better suited to using [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) instead:

```
<%= form_tag managers_managerviewresume_path do %>
    <table class="table" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><%= @selection %></td> //Here I am checking radio button value
            <td>
                <label style="font-size:small;">Selected?</label>
                <label class="radio inline" style="font-size: small">
                </br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%= radio_button_tag :select, "Yes", :id => "rb_select1" %>
                Yes
                </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label class="radio inline" style="font-size: small">
                <%= radio_button_tag :select, "No", :id => "rb_select2" %>
                No
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= submit_tag "Save", { :class => "stylbutton" } %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
<% end %>
```

This syntax might need checking, but this will send the `:select` params as required, which is not what your current form will be doing.

This should be coupled with a `views/managers/managerviewresume.html.erb` file for Rails to load

Comment: your post is working fine but when i click on radio button `No` it show me this `{"No"=>"{:id=>\"rb_select2\"}"}` and when I click on radio button `Yes` it show me this `{"Yes"=>"{:id=>\"rb_select1\"}"} ` and I want to get only `No` and `Yes`.

Comment: I think that's to do with the syntax of the [`radio button`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag) itself - you'll be best doing this:

```radio_button_tag("No", "0", false, id: "rb_select1" )```

Comment: I think you'll have to include a `label` like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746387/labels-for-radio-buttons-in-rails-form - you might be best using [label_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag): `<%= label_tag 'rb_select1', 'No' %>`

Comment: I am using this `<%= radio_button_tag :select, "Yes", :id => "rb_select1" %>` from your post and its working fine but why it checked on `No` radio button and when I check on `Yes` radio button and click on save button, the page refresh and radio button `No` is checked. why?