# radio button with multiple choice of string : can't get the value of the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, simple-form

I have to choose between different strings with my rails form (simple_form_for), but I can't get the value submited. I have seen answers on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746387/labels-for-radio-buttons-in-rails-form), but none of them works.

here is the form in my view:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@prospect, url: new_client_special_order_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.radio_button :context, 'launch product' %>
    <%= f.label :context, 'launch product', value: 'launch product' %>
    <%= f.radio_button :context, "going abroad" %>
    <%= f.label :context, "going abroad", value: "going abroad" %>
    ...
  <% end %>
```

here are the parameters :

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7yRCcJOitjlTN1PhueUfjRTCWR4FflFGIS0McCr/Zt5tHBmR+siSVEX+Sn7o6x6gtzbDlPfqH9ZOziQUG8meqw==", "prospect"=>{"context"=>""}, "commit"=>"Créer mon brief", "controller"=>"home", "action"=>"create_client_prospect_special"}
```

Can you help please, thank you.

Comment: "but I can't get the value in the params." is not helpful to help you. Tell use more. Show us the server log what you see when you submit the form.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I updated the question. it's the only thing interesting you would get in the logs. The string is not sent during the submit action.

Comment: I don't see anything to POST in the params except some standard values..

Comment: Have you tried verifying that :context is permitted?