# How to associate label elements with radio buttons

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some option buttons in my form and I always need to click exactly on the round option button to select it. Is there a way to allow user to click on the associated label to select the option button?

[image]

```
<p>
    <span class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ADR)
    </span>
    <span class="editor-field">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ADR, "Yes", AdrYesOptions) 
        @UserResource.YesValue
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ADR, "No", AdrNoOptions) 
        @UserResource.NoValue 

    </span>
</p>
```

I found some solutions here: [How to associate labels with radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658689/how-to-associate-labels-with-radio-buttons) but these don't suit me because I prefer a solution specific for MVC.

Comment: What do you mean by _specific for MVC_? The linked questions contains a valid answer (though not the accepted one) showing how to achieve this.

Comment: What I mean is (if possible) keeping my code Html.LabelFor... Html.RadioButtonFor... and not something like <label for="option_yes">...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Wrap each radio button and associated label text inside a `<label>` element:

```
<p>
    <span class="editor-label"> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ADR) </span>
    <span class="editor-field">
        <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ADR, "Yes", AdrYesOptions) @UserResource.YesValue </label>
        <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ADR, "No", AdrNoOptions) @UserResource.NoValue </label>
    </span>   
</p>
```

Comment: Note that if the user clicks the main label `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ADR)` this will select the first radio option.